# Calling handler from jQuery doesn't work

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-3.5, handler

I need to call a handler (ashx) file from jQuery to fetch some data at runtime. 
My jQuery function looks like:

```
         var pID = 3;
         var tID = 6;

         $("#Button1").click(function() {
            var urlToHandler = "Controller/TestHandler.ashx";
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: urlToHandler,
                data: "{'pID':'" + pID + "', 'tID':'" + tID + "'}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(msg) {
                    alert(msg);
                }
            });
        });
```

My handler code:

```
 <%@ WebHandler Language="C#" Class="TestHandler" %>

using System;
using System.Web;

public class TestHandler : IHttpHandler
{    
    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context)
    {
        String pID = context.Request.Params["pID"];
        String tID = context.Request.Params["tID"];
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        context.Response.Write(pID + " " + tID);
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the code execution doesn't reach to the handler code.
I can call other web forms (aspx) files from the same jQuery function from the same directory, where the handler file is residing. So it isn't any path issue.

I am new to this handler file concept. I googled a lot but couldn't find anything wrong in my code.

Comment: What does Fiddler say? (Or firebug?)

Comment: So, it's returning 200, success?

Comment: Did you mean "#button1" and not "#Button1"?

Comment: The ID of the button is correct. I have placed alerts & checked that the button click event is firing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the way you are passing the json data to the handler is incorrect.

Also make sure the path to the handler is correct and write a line to the console in the handler to check if it is getting called. Try this code out

```
$("#Button1").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/TestHandler.ashx",
            data: {pID:pID, tID:tID},
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(msg) {
                alert(msg);
            },
            error: function(){
                alert("Error");
            }

        });
    });
```

Comment: The path is correct, I can call other web forms (aspx) files from the same directory. @DRAKO I am trying with the json data correction you suggested.

Answer (score 2):

It worked after changing the way I was passing the json data (as suggested by @DRAKO) and removing the contentType from the ajax post back call. Also corrected the path.

```
$("#Button1").click(function() {
    var urlToHandler = "TestHandler.ashx";
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: urlToHandler,
        data: { pID: pID, tID: tID },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(msg) {
            //do something with the msg here...
        }
    });
});
```